# Remove auto focus from EditText

Tags: android

I have 2 text fields in the start page. But the first text field gets auto focus after launch. I don't want this. I have seen couple of answers regarding this, but none of that work for me.

> My Code

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
```

**I have added two more line here**

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**But still it gets auto focus**

Comment: the lines you added are for requestion focus rather than not focusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`** in manifest file of your Activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".Youractivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

**EDIT**

> **I have added two more line here**

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

> the above line is used for requesting focus rather than not focusing

Comment: What does `android:label="@string/signup"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` these two line do. I got error message CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL

Comment: @ShanBiswas this option if you want to set label and theme in your activity from manifest file than it will use check updated ans

Comment: @ShanBiswas happy to help you

Comment: put this  android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in my edittext is not work